# How to use a custom type correctly in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to use all the power of Symfony to build a site. I already have 2 years of experience in Symfony but for the first time, I am trying to use the concept of custom form type to create a specific registration form. I already have a registration form for basic users but now, I want to create another one for managers whom operate hotels.

I have already created a form type named *RegistrationFormType* and another one named *HotelType*. My thing is that I want to use both of these form types in one form. But I keep getting an exception which says

> Neither the property "user" nor one of the methods "getUser()",
>   "user()", "isUser()", "hasUser()", "__get()" exist and have public
>   access in class "App\Entity\User"

I have followed whatever was said in the Symfony official documentation about custom form types.

I made this form type RegistrationHotelFormType which is made up of another form RegistrationFormType used elsewhere as a form for basic users to create accounts and HotelType generated by Symfony itself.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\HotelType;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

class RegistrationHotelFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', RegistrationFormType::class, ['mapped' => false])
            ->add('hotel', HotelType::class, ['mapped' => false])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This above use to work but in the Symfony documentation, I don't need to set a mapped parameter to false knowing that I want form values to be assigned to objects fields which are Hotel and User. How can I get this done? (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-form-types-created-from-scratch).

RegistrationFormType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['error_bubbling'=>true, 'label' => 'Email', 'attr' => ['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Email', 'aria-label'=>"Username", 'aria-describedby'=>"basic-addon1"]])
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'label' => 'Mot de passe',
                'attr' => ['error_bubbling'=>true, 
                'type'=>'text',
                'class'=>'form-control', 
                'placeholder'=>'Mot de passe', 
                'aria-label'=>"Username", 
                'aria-describedby'=>"basic-addon1"],
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Mot de passe requis',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 8,
                        'minMessage' => 'Le mot de passe doit avoir au moins {{ limit }} caractères',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 128,
                        'maxMessage' => 'Le mot de passe ne doit pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères',
                    ]),
                    // new Regex([
                    //     'pattern' => '/^\S*(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$/',
                    //     'message' => 'Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 1 lettre et 1 chiffre',
                    // ])
                ],
            ])
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, ['error_bubbling'=>true, 'label' => 'Prénom', 'attr' => ['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Prénom', 'aria-label'=>"Username", 'aria-describedby'=>"basic-addon1"]])
            ->add('surname', TextType::class, ['error_bubbling'=>true, 'label' => 'Nom', 'attr' => ['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Nom', 'aria-label'=>"Username", 'aria-describedby'=>"basic-addon1"]])
            ->add('phoneNumber', TextType::class, ['error_bubbling'=>true, 'label' => 'Téléphone', 'attr' => ['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Téléphone', 'aria-label'=>"Username", 'aria-describedby'=>"basic-addon1"]])
            ->add('city', TextType::class, ['error_bubbling'=>true, 'label' => 'Ville', 'attr' => ['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ville', 'aria-label'=>"Username", 'aria-describedby'=>"basic-addon1"]])
            ->add('termsAccepted', CheckboxType::class, [
                'error_bubbling'=>true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => new IsTrue(),
                'attr' => ['type'=>"checkbox", 'class'=>"form-check-input"]
            ])
            ->add('resumePDF', FileType::class, [
                'error_bubbling'=>true,
                'label' => 'CV (Fichier PDF)',
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '1024k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'application/pdf',
                            'application/x-pdf',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Téléchargez un fichier PDF valide',
                    ])
                ],
                'attr' => ['type'=>"file", 'class'=>"custom-file-input"]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

HotelType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Hotel;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class HotelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('address');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Hotel::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

RegistrationController.php

```
    /**
 * @Route("/inscription-hotel", name="app_register_hotel")
 */
public function registerHotel(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, \Swift_Mailer $mailer): Response
{
    $session = new Session();
    // $session->start();

    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationHotelFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    }

    return $this->render('registration/register-hotel.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It is because your hotel registration form type is looking for a property called user ($user->user) to pass to the registration form type.  You will probably encounter the same issue with hotel unless you have a property called $user->hotel.  What you probably need is a RegisteredUser entity which contains both a User and a Hotel entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cerad diagnosed why the error is triggered (the second argument to `createForm` will be used and the form will try to access the `user` and `hotel` property on it), the simplest solution follows:

I would remove the `data_class` from the combined form, and just omit the second parameter to `createForm` in your controller. The return value of `$form->getData()` would be an array:

`['user' => {User object}, 'hotel' => {Hotel object}]`

(you can also provide a similarly structured array to your `createForm` call as the second parameter)

of course, you can create a new class that contains both the user and the hotel...